# How do I compare two list in expect function of flutter unit testing?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart, testing

`List<int> l1=[1,2,3];  List<int> l2=[1,2,3];  expect (l1,l2);`

This is the code I'm using in Flutter unit testing.

Eventhough both of the list has the same content I'm not able to pass the test. I'm not able to find the usecase of comparing lists using Equatable in Flutter unit testing. Can someone please help? Thanks!

Comment: Is this your exact code?  I can't reproduce your problem with the code you've shown. `expect` implicitly uses the `equals` matcher, and the `equals` matcher checks for `List`s and performs an element-wise comparison for equality.

Comment: I see that you've already accepted an answer, but could you please provide a reproducible example?  Even if the accepted answer seems to fix your problem, there probably is something else that's wrong since the code you've shown should already be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the method [ListEquality().equals()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/ListEquality/equals.html) to check if two `List` are equal.

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

List<int> l1 = [1,2,3];  
List<int> l2 = [1,2,3];
final bool equal = ListEquality().equals(l1, l2);
expect(equal, true);
```

Comment: While true, this shouldn't matter when using [`expect`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/expect/expect.html) and its implict [`equals`](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/equals.html) matcher.

Answer (score 0):

List equality works differently in Dart. Since everything is an object you need a mechanism to check each element.

You can use either the `ListEquality` class to compare two lists if they do not have nested objects/informations or, if you want to compare nested objects/informations you can use `DeepCollectionEquality`. Both come from collections library which comes out of the box with Dart.

You can check the following examples of the usages:

```
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

void main() {
  const numberListOne = [1,2,3];
  const numberListTwo = [1,2,3];
  
  final _listEquality = ListEquality();
  print(_listEquality.equals(numberListOne, numberListTwo));
}
```

Comment: While true, this shouldn't matter when using [`expect`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/expect/expect.html) and its implict [`equals`](https://pub.dev/documentation/matcher/latest/matcher/equals.html) matcher.